# How to zero out bottom n bits in a C unsigned int?

Tags: c

I am trying to write my own C floor function. I am stuck on this code detail. I would just like to know how I can zero out the bottom n bits of an unsigned int.

For example, to round 51.5 to 51.0, I need to zero out the bottom 18 bits, and keep the top 14. Since it's a floor function, I want to make a mask to zero out the bottom (23 minus exponent) bits from the float representation. I know how to make a mask for individual cases like that, but I'm not sure how to code it so that it will work for all. Please help.

Comment: `int floor(float number) { return (int)number;}` works

Comment: Make up your mind - is the number and unsigned short or a float? What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, just edited. The number is an unsigned int

Comment: I'm trying to zero out the bottom bits of the unsigned int.

Comment: I have worked out some examples. To round 51.5 to 51.0, I need to keep the top 14 bits of the number. So I would do number & FFF20000. But since it will be different every time, I am not sure how to write something that will work for all of them.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Unless the number is negative...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A much simpler way is doing just this:

```
value = (value >> bits) << bits
```

because the shift left will fill it in with zeroes, not whatever was in there.

Comment: I particularly like this one. Very elegant.

Comment: Thanks a lot to you both!!

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what bits and value are here? In my example where I am trying to keep the top 14 bits, is it true that the mask should be this: value = (value >> 14) << 18

Answer (score 3):

Shift a number left N bits. Subtract one. Invert the bits. And with the number you need to mask.

```
1 << 14 = 00000000000000000010000000000000
     -1 = 00000000000000000001111111111111
     ~  = 11111111111111111110000000000000
```

When you `and` with this, a 1 in the mask will preserve the input, and 0 in the mask will set the result to 0.